# Fastest way to search multiple words and concatenate the searched word with "a_" in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] words = { "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl" };
        String text = "My name is abc, I am from def, want to go ghi to meet jkl";

        for (String str : words) {
            text = text.replaceAll(str, "a_" + str);

        }

        System.out.println(text);
        
    }
```

In the example above, list of strings and text is small. But, in real time the list and text will be huge.

Comment: `replaceAll` expects a regular expression as passed parameter. Is your replacement meant to work with regular expressions? Otherwise i would recommend switching to the `replace` method. (They are really badly named, replace also replaces all occurences but does not use regex)

Comment: Yeah, replace can be used. Regular expression will not be useful for me. Is there any other way apart from replace and replaceAll? Any efficient way to reduce number of loops?

Comment: if we take the words length as N, and text length as M, you are doing it in O(N*M),
I think you can create a finite state machine of the words, then split the text to words and try to traverse the FSM for every word of text, it would be O(M) I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Could not say below is the fastest solution as without loop it won't be possible to solve this problem but if you don't want to use regex and for loop then you could try solving using [Apache's StringUtils.replaceEach](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceEach-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-) method as follows:-

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String[] words = { "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl" };
    String[] replacement_words = Arrays.stream(words).map(word-> "a_".concat(word)).toArray(String[]::new);
    String text = "My name is abc, I am from def, want to go ghi to meet jkl";
    String replaced_text = StringUtils.replaceEach(text,words,replacement_words);
    System.out.println(replaced_text);
}
```

Output of code:-

```
My name is a_abc, I am from a_def, want to go a_ghi to meet a_jkl
```